# NiFi - Create Database Table From JSON

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to read a JSON file and create a table based on its schema.

I'm supposed to do this though `NiFi` and I'm new to it, so I've broken down the problem into the following parts

1. Read JSON File, extract its schema
2. Once the correct schema is extracted, use it to generate a create statement
3. Execute the create statement

For the first point, the approach I'm using is

```
GetFile > InferAvroSchema > EvaluateJsonPath > PutFile
```

My JSON file looks like this

```
{"data":[
{
  "firstname":"John",
  "lastname":"Snow",
  "age":24
}
]}
```

The output of `InferAvroSchema` (when sent to `PutFile`) is

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "MyRec",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "data",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "data",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "firstname",
          "type" : "string",
          "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"John\"'"
        }, {
          "name" : "lastname",
          "type" : "string",
          "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"Snow\"'"
        }, {
          "name" : "age",
          "type" : "int",
          "doc" : "Type inferred from '24'"
        } ]
      }
    },
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '[{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Snow\",\"age\":24}]'"
  } ]
}
```

So, I try to read the schema in `EvaluateJsonPath` as `$.fields[0].type.items.fields`.

The `EvaluateJsonPath` processor config is as follows
[image: config]

When I try to see the data provenance, I don't see any attribute called `colz`. But if I send its output to a `PutFile`, I get this

```
    [
  {
    "name":"firstname",
    "type":"string",
    "doc":"Type inferred from '\"John\"'"
  },
  {
    "name":"lastname",
    "type":"string",
    "doc":"Type inferred from '\"Snow\"'"
  },
  {
    "name":"age",
    "type":"int",
    "doc":"Type inferred from '24'"
  }
]
```

Which is an array. Now I was hoping to be able to loop through this array through some script and create a string (for the create statement) with name and type attributes.

Could someone guide me as to how I could get this array in a script (for the looping)?

Also, is my approach fine or is there a better way to achieve this result?

I use NiFi 1.8.0. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: seems to be similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053901/create-a-postgresql-table-from-avro-schema-in-nifi/49076714#49076714